# Angular 6: Rewriting URLs using .htaacces in httpd is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite all URL in my Angular 6 application. I've tried many rules and nothing worked.

.htaacess works, because this rule is working fine:

```
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Tried rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^#/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^#/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^/#/(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^#/(.*)$ /$1 [N]
```

My urls look like this: **www.domain.pl/#/login** and I want to rewrite them to **www.domain.pl/login**

Comment: This question isn't related to Angular, I'm removing the tag

Comment: Duplicate of [create link /#/example/12345 with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51276212/3150271)

Comment: Oh, @Anonymous thanks for reply :/

Comment: @Anonymous I've resolved it differently ;)

Comment: @MaciejSocha Great. I’m glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this problem with adding this in AppModule Providers:

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```

and importing

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

After that I created .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Now everything works great without # in URLs :)

Comment: this worked for my scenario (angular 11 and Apache with reverse proxy)

Comment: This didn't work for me with latest version of Ionic (based on Angular).